# How to check what was clicked in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check what was clicked on whole document and save this information to target variable.

I want to make some logic with knowledge about clicked target.

Here is sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Document is Ready");
    event = "";
    previousEvent = "";
    function init()
    {
        event = "";
        target = "";
    } init();
    function loop()
    {
        if(event==previousEvent) {event="EVENT_NOTHING"; }
        if(event!=previousEvent&&event!="EVENT_NOTHING") {
            console.log("EVENT: " + event);
            // (...) some logic (...)
        }

        previousEvent = event;
    }
    loop = setInterval(loop,100);

    //EVENTS
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        var key = e.which;
        if(key == "37")      event = "EVENT_KEYPRESS_LEFTARROW";
        else if(key == "38") event = "EVENT_KEYPRESS_UPARROW";
        else if(key == "39") event = "EVENT_KEYPRESS_RIGHTARROW";
        else if(key == "40") event = "EVENT_KEYPRESS_DOWNARROW";
        else {event = "EVENT_KEYPRESS_UNBINDED";}
    });

    $(document).click(function(){
        event = "EVENT_KEYPRESS_CLICK";
        target = ???????; //for example element in canvas, or any tag in html
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event has a target property

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    event = "EVENT_KEYPRESS_CLICK";
    target = e.target;
});
```

Comment: it works great :) Even better than I thought :D It gives me full response about clicked element, e.g. <button id="myAwesomeButton1" class="myAwesomeClass myAwesomeClass2"> :)

Answer (score -1):

You can get the target in a jquery event as `$(this)`. You can use any jQuery function on this object.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var event = "EVENT_KEYPRESS_CLICK";
    var target = $(this);
});
```

Comment: You are setting the `$(document)` as a target, so you are asking the id of the document. you should at least do `$("div").click()` to target all divs. But still better, you should target a class or an id.

Comment: What I want to say is that your answer is totally incorrect.

Comment: I want to set as a target clicked element, not document element ;) So, sorry, this answer is invalid :)